# IntelliJ UE 2023.1 starting Spring boot app in debug mode really slow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug my Spring Boot application. It starts up fine when not in debug mode within 5 seconds and I can hit my APIs through Postman correctly. However, when I try to start it in debug mode, it looks like it just hangs and then starts on the configured port about 10 minutes later.

**Normal mode**

```
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:59:32.912","msg":"HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.0.Final","logger":"org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version","level":"INFO"}
Jun 28, 2023 4:59:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Jun 28, 2023 4:59:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jun 28, 2023 4:59:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
Jun 28, 2023 4:59:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:59:35.838","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Starting...","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:59:36.296","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3b3b38b8","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:59:36.298","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Start completed.","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:59:36.350","msg":"HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]","logger":"org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:59:36.400","msg":"HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final","logger":"org.hibernate.Version","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:59:36.786","msg":"HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect","logger":"SQL dialect","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:59:37.765","msg":"HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]","logger":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator","level":"INFO"}
Jun 28, 2023 4:59:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Jun 28, 2023 4:59:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

From the above timestamps, normal mode starts up within a couple of seconds.

**Debug mode**

```
C:\PROGRA~1\RedHat\Java\OpenJDK17\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:3415,suspend=y,server=n -Ddebug -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*" -javaagent:C:\Users\syy\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "JARS_HERE" dev.test.webservice.Application
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:3415', transport: 'socket'
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.430","msg":"HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.0.Final","logger":"org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.697","msg":"Starting application using Java 17.0.5 with PID 20844 (started by syy in C:\\projects\\test-project\\dqc-test-webservice)","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.699","msg":"Running with Spring Boot v3.0.0, Spring v6.0.2","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.700","msg":"The following 1 profile is active: \"local\"","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.702","msg":"Loading source class dev.test.webservice.Application","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.867","msg":"Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/projects/test-project/target/classes/]","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.868","msg":"Included patterns for restart : []","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.868","msg":"Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter-[\\w-]+/, /spring-boot/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-starter/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-devtools/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-actuator/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/(bin|build|out)/]","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.868","msg":"Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.869","msg":"For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:08.871","msg":"Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@54ccaeb2","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.382","msg":"Code archive: C:\\Users\\syy\\.m2\\repository\\org\\springframework\\boot\\spring-boot\\3.0.0\\spring-boot-3.0.0.jar","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.383","msg":"Code archive: C:\\Users\\syy\\.m2\\repository\\org\\springframework\\boot\\spring-boot\\3.0.0\\spring-boot-3.0.0.jar","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.383","msg":"None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.455","msg":"Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer","level":"INFO"}
Jun 28, 2023 4:30:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Jun 28, 2023 4:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jun 28, 2023 4:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
Jun 28, 2023 4:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.616","msg":"Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.619","msg":"Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3745 ms","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.807","msg":"Mapping filters: filterRegistrationBean urls=[/*] order=-2147483647, springSecurityFilterChain urls=[/*] order=-100, characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*] order=-2147483648, formContentFilter urls=[/*] order=-9900, requestContextFilter urls=[/*] order=-105","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.807","msg":"Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/]","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.839","msg":"Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured for use","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.846","msg":"Filter 'serverHttpObservationFilter' configured for use","logger":"org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.846","msg":"Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured for use","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.847","msg":"Filter 'springSecurityFilterChain' configured for use","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean$1","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.847","msg":"Filter 'formContentFilter' configured for use","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.907","msg":"@EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'dev.test.webservice'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.","logger":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:12.959","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Starting...","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:13.466","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3a47a16","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:13.468","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Start completed.","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:13.505","msg":"HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]","logger":"org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:13.554","msg":"HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final","logger":"org.hibernate.Version","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:14.079","msg":"HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect","logger":"SQL dialect","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:30:15.570","msg":"HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]","logger":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:31:22.390","msg":"spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning","logger":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration","level":"WARN"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:31:28.373","msg":"\r\n\r\nUsing generated security password: asd2321-7aas3-016-xa2e-10as5gg31f00\r\n\r\nThis generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.\r\n","logger":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration","level":"WARN"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:32:05.764","msg":"ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice","logger":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:32:13.838","msg":"13 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'","logger":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:39:21.349","msg":"Patterns [/webjars/**, /**, /swagger-ui*/*swagger-initializer.js, /swagger-ui*/**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'","logger":"org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:39:27.369","msg":"ControllerAdvice beans: 1 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice","logger":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:40:24.924","msg":"Application Admin MBean registered with name 'org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication'","logger":"org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:40:33.781","msg":"Starting live reload server on port 35729","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.livereload.LiveReloadServer","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:40:33.807","msg":"LiveReload server is running on port 35729","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.OptionalLiveReloadServer","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:40:37.856","msg":"Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'","logger":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver","level":"INFO"}
Jun 28, 2023 4:41:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:41:01.211","msg":"Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:41:08.925","msg":"Started application in 661.213 seconds (process running for 663.654)","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:41:09.365","msg":"Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT","logger":"org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityBean","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:41:09.494","msg":"Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:41:09.497","msg":"Immediately restarting application","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:41:09.498","msg":"Starting application dev.test.webservice.Application with URLs [file:/C:/projects/test-project/target/classes/]","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter","level":"DEBUG"}
{"time":"2023-06-28 16:41:09.580","msg":"Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC","logger":"org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityBean","level":"DEBUG"}
```

As you can see from the debug timestamps above, I start up the server in debug mode around 16:30 but it doesn't fully initialize on the specified port until 16:41.

```
Jun 28, 2023 4:41:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
```

In addition, once it's started, any debugging I do is executed really slow. For example, if I have a breakpoint at the beginning of the flow, it doesn't hit that breakpoint until 2 minutes later.

Any information as to why it's starting up and going so slow in debug mode would be appreciated.

Comment: How much memory does your machine have?  How much memory have you allocated to IntelliJ?  What does the Windows process monitor show you in terms of memory usage?  Debugging is an expensive operation - you'll need alot of memory and alot of CPU.

Comment: My machine has 64GB of ram. IntelliJ usually uses around 2-4GB of memory. Not sure how to check how much I've allocated to IntelliJ. However, I restarted my computer and now it's starting up in debug mode within 5 seconds. Do you think there could have been a memory leak before the restart to cause it to take 10 minutes? I restarted IntelliJ when the issue was happening but it was still taking 10 minutes to start.

Comment: I thinks it's likely that the memory in you machine was fragmented and the reboot allowed for simpler memory allocation.  Any more than that is a bit of a guess as it sounds like you've got a decent sized application.

Comment: Interesting. I'll pay more close attention if it happens again. The application is pretty small, however. I just started it. No more than 5 small files.